# Obtaining value via $ref / self reference

Tags: javascript, json, self-reference

I'd like to to use a reference to refer to an existing object within my JSON structure; specifically access it's keys and values.

I thought it reasonable that I *should* be able to refer to an existing object and then use dot notation to access said keys and values - but more likely I'm misunderstanding the technology.

```
var courses = {
            Engl101 : {
                course : "English 101",
                units : 5,
                req_type : false ,
                req: false
            },
            Engl112: {
                course : "English 112",
                units : 3,
                req_type : "prerequisite" ,
                req: { "$ref": "#/courses/Engl101"}
            }
        }
```

I expected I should be able to then access my prerequisite course with

```
courses.Engl112.req
```

What I actually get appears to be a string with no access to child keys/values.

Also, I tried to access via `Object.keys(courses.Engl112.req)` with variations of [0] numerated indices with no real progress.

Is this feasible and thank you in advance?

Comment: What you have there is a JS object literal, not JSON.  JSON is *always* a string representation of a JS object.

Comment: Hi Amy, thank you for your explanation. Just curious: Would this be fundamentally different if it were accessed via fetch() -ing a JSON file vs an Object { } within my script tag?

Comment: When you ask "would *this* be fundamentally different", what is "this" referring to?

Comment: Sorry to clarify, I didn't mean 'this' the contextual object - I just was wondering if accessing JSON data was any different when looking at an object instantiated within script tags:
let object = {...}  
versus fetching an external object from a JSON file or AJAX call..
ex: fetch('JSON_file.json')...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your courses are unique by name you could put

```
req: "English101"
```

You could then access the required courses by

```
courses[courses.Engl112.req]
```

Comment: Brilliant Pierre! Thank you kindly - this worked perfectly.
Thank you for taking the time to answer this for me. 

I am confused by the syntax - it looks like it's accessing my courses variable and the target is in an array ?? Or perhaps this is the same as when I iterate through a for loop (ex: Object[i].nested_Content).

Could you point towards a resource, I could use to educate myself. Many thanks!

Comment: I'll try to briefly explain what is going on here, first your json data is an object just like a string and basically anything else in js so when you want to get a course like Engl101 you can do this in 2 ways: firstly by using myCourse.Engl101 and secondly by using myCourses["Engl101"]  so then when your req is a string you can do what I did in the answer by combing both methods. Regarding ressources: I would recommend you to look how objects work in js, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript, you cannot do such a thing.
But some libraries exist to support internal and external references in JSON. A famous one: [json-schema-ref-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-ref-parser).

Comment: Thank you for the resource Brice. I'll certainly do some investigating